# Impossibility of constructing a continuum-size linearly independent set in $\Bbb R$

Tags: linear-algebra, set-theory, cardinals, axiom-of-choice

This is a response to the following exchange at [Is there a quick proof as to why the vector space of $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is infinite-dimensional?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6244/is-there-a-quick-proof-as-to-why-the-vector-space-of-mathbbr-over-mathbb?lq=1)

> > [Bill constructs a $\aleph_0$ linearly independent set in $\Bbb R$]
>
> Can you extend the idea of this proof to get the right dimension? Currently, you only have a countably infinite independent set, but the dimension is size continuum. – [JDH Jun 23 '11 at 2:22](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6244/is-there-a-quick-proof-as-to-why-the-vector-space-of-mathbbr-over-mathbb?lq=1#comment104850_6250)

I believe the answer to this question is *no*, for the following reason. Suppose we have a spanning set for $\Bbb R$ over $\Bbb Q$, of cardinality $\frak n$. Then by definition we have the cardinality equation ${\frak c}\le^*[{\frak n}]^{<\omega}\cdot \aleph_0$ (where $[{\frak n}]^{<\omega}$ is the cardinality of finite subsets, and $\frak m\le^*n$ means there is a surjection from $\frak n$ to $\frak m$).

If $\frak n$ is finite, then we get ${\frak c}\le^*\aleph_0$ which is false, so $\frak n$ is infinite (but not necessarily Dedekind-infinite). If we assume the axiom of choice, then the equation reduces to $\frak c\le n$, hence every Hamel basis is size continuum. But without AC I don't know any way to simplify the original equation to get anything stronger than "$\frak n$ is infinite".

This is at best heuristic evidence for the original question, since it is considering a different problem (spanning sets instead of linearly independent sets). How could one show that there are no ZF-constructible $\Bbb Q$-linearly independent subsets of $\Bbb R$ of cardinality continuum?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/a/32549/7206 (which leads to http://mathoverflow.net/a/23206/7206)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Beautiful. Feel free to post that as an answer so I can close the Q.

Comment: Also related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1696284/is-there-any-uncountably-infinite-set-that-does-not-generate-the-reals/1696288#1696288 (which links to the second answer Asaf linked to).

Comment: I'd rather not. It's not even my own work. Just a link to previous answers on MO.

Comment: @AsafKaragila What's the protocol for "close as dupe in MO"? (Mark it as CW if that is what bothers you.)

Comment: I'm already in bed. You do whatever you want.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Your dedication is impressive.