# For an uncountable set of irrationals whose countable subsets sums all converge, is there one such countable subset which sums to a rational?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, examples-counterexamples, irrational-numbers

This is a variation of [Let $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ be an uncountable set of irrational numbers. Does there exist a finite $B\subset A$ such that $\sum_{x\in B} x\in\mathbb{Q}?$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4837031/746936), relaxing the finiteness hypothesis on $B \subset A$ to countability, but demanding good behaviour on these with respect to summation

Comment: This is too broad.  If say, all your irrationals are greater than $1$, then no such sum can converge in the usual sense.  For example.

Comment: @lulu: But then the sums of countable subsets wouldn't converge, either?

Comment: @joriki  Maybe I'm misreading.  I thought the OP wanted a countably infinite subset of $A$ which summed to a rational...but if every element of $A$ was $>1$ then no such sum could converge at all (let alone to a rational).  Do you think something else was intended?

Comment: @lulu, yep, that's precisely  what I want, and the "all countable subsets do in fact sum to something" hypothesis is there to eliminate cases such as the one you've brought up (but it may well be that no such $A$ exists, I don't really know)

Comment: I think that there is an issue with "countable subsets sums all converge", as that would force uncountably many of the elements to be 0.

Comment: Oh, I see.  I disregarded the requirement that all countable subsets have convergent sums...but of course, that requirement is essentially impossible.  You could only have finitely many elements $>\frac 1n$ for each $n$, forcing the set to be countable.